# Can I replace my graphics card?

Tags: graphics-card, upgrade, amd-radeon, asus-laptop

I have an Asus Vivobook X54UP I5 laptop which has AMD Radeon R5 M420 , with 2GB, VRAM graphics card and I want to replace it to a higher version or if possible, with an NVidia graphics card but I am not sure if it can be replaced.

So thank you very much for the answers aka help.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it's possible, not sure if you can switch vendors but in general, laptop gpus are soldered down to the motherboard, to replace them you would have to desolder them to remove them, then solder in the new one, but this is a very difficult process that an amateur has like 0% chances of successfully doing it.

And even if it's successfully done, it's quite possible the gpu won't fit, I imagine you will need to buy a replacement gpu that is the same die size and from the same line of cards (e.g. it's possible you could replace it with a m480 but not a 1060m or anything like that)

Overall, it's a pain in the ass to do, requires professional work, unlikely to actually work even if you successfully solder another card back in. So while technically it's possible...

**The answer for you is no**.

Normally your best bet would be buying an external gpu but these require a thunderbolt 3 port (or better) which your laptop does not have. So your only option is buying a better laptop or buying a pc.